# how to show that $\det\left(xB+yB^T\right)$ is a multiple of $x+y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, transpose

> Let $B$ be a $3\times3$ matrix, and let $f(x,y)= \det\left(xB+yB^T\right)$. Show that $\det\left(xB+yB^T\right)$ is a multiple of $x+y$, where $x,y$ are any real numbers and $B$ is any $3 \times 3$ matrix with real entries.

I can only think a tedious method to show this question by assuming a determinant to do it. Can anyone give me a idea or method to finish it easily?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y) = \det(xB + yB^T)$. Then $f(x, -x) = \det(xB - xB^T) = x^3 \det(B- B^T)$

The matrix $A= B-B^T$ is an odd-size skew-symmetric $(A^T = -A)$ matrix. Since $\det(A^T)  = \det(A)$ and $\det(-A) = (-1)^3 \det(A) = -\det(A)$, it follows that $\det(A) = 0$.

Added: $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] = (\mathbb{R}[x])[y]$ is a polynomial, hence $f(x,y) = (x+y)g(x,y) + h(x)$. Therefore $x+y$ divides $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ if and only if $h(x) = 0$, and the latter is equivalent to $f(x, -x) = 0$.

Comment: Since it's not obvious how you approached this, you should say explicitly that for a general polynomial $p(x,y)$ on two variables, $(x + y) \mid p(x,y)$ if and only if $p(x,-x) = 0$.

Comment: Or perhaps the less complicated version is this: saying that a function $f$ divides a function $g$ really means that if $f = 0$, then $g = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am a bit confused, it is necessary, but not really sufficient in general.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I agree - multiplicities can play a tricky role sometimes ... For example $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$.

Comment: That was a bit of a careless statement, then. Thanks for the correction

Comment: This is **exactly the same question** (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3582940) you have posted 3 hours before this one. Ii is a **bad way of using this site**. I had given you an answer (very similar to the answer by @Catalin Zara), The least you should have done is mentionning the previous question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have added an edit to my previous answer to the initial question (math.stackexchange.com/q/3582940) generalizing this factorization (therefore providing a way to manage possible multiplicities)