# Determinantal representation formula for bivariate polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have read in this paper http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2015.182.1.8 that for any real stable polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[z_1,z_2]$ of degree exactly $d$, there exists $d \times d$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $A$ and $B$ and a symmetric matrix $C$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
p(z_1,z_2)=\pm \det (z_1A+z_2B+C).
\end{equation*}
Here real stable just means that $p$ is stable and has real coefficients. In the same paper it is stated that: For any $z_1,z_2>0$, $z_1A+z_2B$ is positive definite (*).  They argue by contradiction, and say that if (*) does not hold, there is a non-zero vector in the null-space of both $A$ and $B$. This I get. Then they claim that this implies that the degree of $p$ must be less then $d$, arriving at a contraction. My question is: Why is this last implication true?

I guess that the idea is to relate the determinant expression to the coefficients of the highest degree monomials of $p$. I tried expanding $p(z_1,z_2)=\det(z_1A+z_2B+C)$ using the definition involving permutations, and if I am not mistaking, this gives something of the form $\det(A)z_1^d+\det(B)z_2^d+\sum_{i=1}^{d-1}k_iz_1^{d-i}z_2^{i}$ (plus monomials in $z_1,z_2$ of degree less than $d$) for some coefficients $k_i$ that depend on the matrices $A, B$ and $C$.  I know that $\det(A)=0=\det(B)$, but don't we also need to know that all the $k_i$'s are zero in order to conclude that $p$ has degree less than $d$? I tried to find expressions for the $k_i$'s involving $\det(A), \det(B)$, but without luck...

Is there some sort of formula for these coefficients that could be usefull? Or is there a better/easier way to see why (*) is true? Chances are that I am overlooking something obvious, and any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Recall that "stable polynomial " means "either all its roots lie in the open left half-plane, or all its roots lie in the open unit disk." (adjective "stable" for this isn't common in the mathematical community).

Comment: The link you give doesn't allow access to the document to "unauthorized" people ; il should be replaced by https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3969.pdf

Comment: All right, I was not aware of this more common definition, I will edit that in my question. Thanks! And thank you for making me aware that the link did not work as intended.

Comment: Thank you to you for having driven our attention to this interesting issue. I recently solved an issue on matrices' "pencils" like this one which happened to be connected to characteristic polynomials  (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3582975); hopefuly, your issue could also have something to do with (generalized) characteristic polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ have a common non-zero vector in the nullspace, then $p(z_1,z_2)=\pm \det (z_1A+z_2B+C)$ indeed has degree less than $d$.  We can see this as follows:

Suppose that $x$ is a unit-vector and that $Ax = Bx = 0$.  Let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix whose first column is $x$.  Note (or show) that $U^TAU$ and $U^TBU$ have zeros in their first row and column.  We see that
$$
 \det (z_1A+z_2B+C) = 
 \det (U^T[z_1A+z_2B+C]U) \\
= 
\det(z_1[U^TAU] + z_2[U^TBU] + U^TCU).
$$
Since the matrix $M(z_1,z_2) =  z_1[U^TAU] + z_2[U^TBU] + U^TCU$ has no variables in its first row, we can conclude that its determinant has (total) degree at most $d-1$.

Comment: I see, I understand that. Thank you for your help :)