# Determinant of the strain tensor?

Tags: determinant, tensors, fluid-dynamics

In fluid mechanics, we often decompose the tensor $\nabla\boldsymbol u$ into its symmetric and antisymmetric parts, called the strain rate tensor and the vorticity tensor respectively,
$$\nabla\boldsymbol u=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\big(\nabla \boldsymbol u+(\nabla\boldsymbol u)^\intercal\big)}_{:=\boldsymbol \varepsilon}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\big(\nabla \boldsymbol u-(\nabla\boldsymbol u)^\intercal\big)}_{:=\boldsymbol \Omega}$$
These tensors are all of shape $(1,1)$ and so are bona-fide matrices, so their determinant makes sense.

Clearly, $\det(\nabla\boldsymbol u)$ is just the Jacobian determinant of $\boldsymbol u$. The relevance of this is obvious. It is also obvious that $\operatorname{tr}\nabla\boldsymbol u=\operatorname{tr}\boldsymbol \varepsilon=\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol u$. The significance of this is also clear.

However, what can we say about $\det\boldsymbol \varepsilon$ and $\det\boldsymbol \Omega$? Do these have any physical significance? Knowing these quantities, what can we say, qualitatively and quantitatively, about the flow field $\boldsymbol u$? I tried computing these quantities in general but I just ended up with a complete mess of indices. I **do** know that [in an odd number of dimensions, the determinant of an antisymmetric matrix is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287709/prove-that-determinant-of-an-odd-dimension-anti-symmetric-matrix-is-zero). But what about two dimensional flows? What then?

### **Motivation:**

In my fluid mechanics course, I have solved for the two dimensional incompressible steady flow field
$$\boldsymbol{u}\left(\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix} ( E+\Omega) y\\ ( E-\Omega) x \end{bmatrix}$$
I am asked to:

> Compute the rate-of-strain tensor $\boldsymbol \varepsilon$ and the vorticity tensor $\boldsymbol \Omega$. Comment on the results in the five cases

> **1:** $\Omega=0, E\neq 0$
> **2:** $\Omega\neq 0, E=0$
> **3:** $\Omega=E$
> **4:** $\Omega<E$
> **5:** $\Omega>E$

I have computed the strain rate and vorticity tensors,
$$\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & E\\
E & 0
\end{bmatrix} \ \ ;\ \ \boldsymbol{\Omega} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \Omega\\
-\Omega & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

But I'm having problems seeing the physical significance of the five different cases. Clearly when $\Omega=0$ then $\operatorname{curl}\boldsymbol u=0$, but what else?

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a start.

To understand the nature of these flows, you should try to plot streamlines.
It is also helpful to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the rate-of-strain tensor which are the principal strain rates and principal axes of strain.

(1) If $\Omega = 0$ and $E > 0$, then the principal strain rates (eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$) are $\pm E$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(1,1)^T$ and $(1,-1)^T$.  Hence, the principal axes of strain are oriented at $+45$ degrees and $-45$ degrees with respect to the $x$-axis. This is an example of biaxial extensional flow where the streamlines are hyperbolas with these principal strain axes as asymptotes.   Fluid particles are stretched and compressed in directions parallel to the principal strain axes oriented at $+45$ degrees and $-45$ degrees, respectively.

(2) If $\Omega \neq 0$ and $E = 0$ we have a rigid rotation with circular streamlines.

(3) If $\Omega = E$ we have a simple unidirectional shear flow with $u = 2Ey$ and $v = 0$.

Comment: I did not think to plot the streamlines, or to consider the eigenvectors. Thank you for this advice; I will experiment with this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me come up with some good results for my assignment. Is there anything to be said about the general case when $\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol u\neq 0$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite: You're welcome.  For these flows you should see closed streamlines transition from circles to ellipses of increasing eccentricity as we increase $E$ from $0$. When we reach $E = \Omega$ the streamlines are straight lines in shear flow. As $E$ is increased with $E > \Omega$ the streamlines should be hyperbolic.   This is the kinematic behavior of the flow in your problem which happens to satisfy $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking in the general case $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \neq 0$ where the flow is compressible. The rate-of-strain and vorticity tensors have the same physical interpretation.

Comment: I meant, for an arbitrary solution of the N-S equations, is there anything we can qualitatively say about it based on the determinants of the strain rate and vorticity tensors? If the answer is no, that's fine.