# Symplectic manifolds should be odd dimensional

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I read that the necessary condition for a manifold to be symplectic is that it should be even dimensional. The justification give is that an odd dimensional skew symmetric matrix is singular.
Therefore there exists a $\omega^j$ for which $\omega_{ij}u^j = 0$.
This means that for all  $v$ $\epsilon$ $T_PM$,

$\omega(v\otimes u)=\omega_{ij}v^iu^j=0$

How does odd dimensional skew symmetric matrix being singular leads to the existence of such a $u^j$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287709/prove-that-determinant-of-an-odd-dimension-anti-symmetric-matrix-is-zero).

Comment: This is just the definition of "singular": there is a nonzero vector $u$ in its kernel.